# Protocols & assign properties in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, ios5

I'm trying to create my own **Custom Delegates** in **iOS 5**.
In iOS 4, I usually used the **'Assign' property**:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<AnyProtocol> delegate;
```

Now, when I try to **synthesize**, I get the following error message:

```
error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Existing ivar 'delegate' for unsafe_unretained property 'delegate' must be __unsafe_unretained
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753841/recommended-way-to-declare-delegate-properties-with-arc/7755248#7755248

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error is because under ARC ivars default to strong

What this error is telling you that you've declared a property with `__unsafe_unretained` (assign) ownership, but by default ivar have `__strong` ownership, so they can't be in one. You can

1. Omit the ivar, which will be automatically created
2. Define the ivar to match your (assign) property declaration:

   ```
   __unsafe_unretained id <FileListDelegate> delegate;
   ```
3. Define the property to match the ivar's implicit `__strong` ownership:

   ```
    @property (weak) id <FileListDelegate> delegate;
   ```

The three options shamelessly copied from user chrispix's answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773295/cant-get-custom-protocol-working-on-ios) thread..Credit goes there